# multiple ajax with async false for all browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am making multiple ajax calls at a time

Example:

```
  $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         url:url1,
         aysnc:false,
         beforeSend:function()
         {
               $("#loader").show();
         },
         success:function(data)
         {
            ///.....do manipulation
            $("#loader").hide();
          }
       });


       $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         url:url1,
         aysnc:false,
         beforeSend:function()
         {
               $("#loader").show();
         },
         success:function(data)
         {
            ///.....do manipulation
            $("#loader").hide();
          }
       });

       $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         url:url1,
         aysnc:false,
         beforeSend:function()
         {
               $("#loader").show();
         },
         success:function(data)
         {
            ///.....do manipulation
            $("#loader").hide();
          }
       });
```

I need to show loader until ajax succeeded the above code works only in FIREFOX but not in IE and CHROME as the loader is not seen but my ajax are getting called please help i tried all solution

Answer (score 1):

Some of browsers stop all animation when we call ajax with aysnc:false.

I have one solution: First call first ajax and put other to first ajax's success function...

Like this, you can set all ajax nested. So, You can start loader with first ajax call and stop with last ajax call...

Something like this...

```
$("#loader").show();

$.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url:url1,

     success:function(data)
     {
        ///.....do manipulation

        $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         url:url1,
         beforeSend:function()
         {
               $("#loader").show();
         },
        success:function(data)
         {
            ///.....do manipulation
            $("#loader").hide();
          }
        });


      }
   });
```

Comment: Ya your are absolutely right but it flows till second ajax call and fails to call third ajax

Answer (score 0):

Never use synchronous ajax calls, work around the asynchronous nature of ajax instead. In other words, stay as far away from the `async` setting as humanly possible, don't give in to the urge to set it to false, as it defeats the entire purpose of ajax.

To do this with multiple async calls, you should be using [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to capture all the promises returned by the ajax functions, and then fire a callback when they are all done, something like this

```
function doAjax() {
    $("#loader").show();
    $.when(
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : url1
        }),
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : url2
        }),
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : url3
        })
    ).done(function() {
        $("#loader").hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: I have tried these but the loader doesn't get hide :( :(